# How to share WPF XAML file with designer and Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get my designer to update our xaml files with a better look and feel. I was hoping to give her just the xaml file and Expression Blend and let her go wild with it, but now I notice that Expression Blend does not seem to have any way of opening an actual xaml file by itself but is expecting a whole project.

Is there any way that this can be done? How would I share a xaml file with a designer without giving them all the code but just the UI files?

Answer (score 0):

You share the whole project.

You have to trust them not to edit stuff outside the UI. If they are using Expression Blend then, while they can edit the code it is focused on making UI changes.

Also if you are using source control you can track their changes and rollback any that cause problems.

Comment: Seems like a total non-feature. The ability to split the ui and backend is what sold the idea of WPF for me, and now it seems it's just a farce. I would not like them to even _see_ the code. It's private IP.

Comment: You can do code edits and stuff in blend just fine, you just don't have all the same functionality as VS.

Comment: @ChrisW. - yeah - I wasn't 100% sure, it's been a while since I used it.

Comment: @ChrisW. but how do I get the xaml file to her? There is no open file command, only open project, no import and drag drop doesn't work.

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic There's a reason Blend wants to open whole projects instead of single files since it's going to need the different libraries/namespaces/resource files the file will likely require to render correctly anyway. She could open a blank project and just copy/paste the code into a new window/usercontrol or whatever. Or if they're just light edits use something like [Kxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/). Otherwise to do her job, you may as well give access to the whole solution so she can get to res dictionaries etc. she might need.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW. makes sense I suppose.

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic yea it can be an added pain in the butt, except somewhat unavoidable in some cases, like you may see something like `<ComboBox>` in the code, but somewhere needs to be a style template to tell that object what it actually is, and she'd be missing that if she opened just a single file, would also make it pretty difficult to apply real -global- design changes just within single files at a time without access to resource dictionaries and everything.